# How to use regex for words

Tags: python, regex

I was trying a simple regex code to match the following:

```
line = 'blah black blacksheep blah' 
if re.match(r'(\bblack\b)', line):
    print 'found it!
```

What am I doing wrong, I can't find "black" by itself?

Comment: `Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.` Use `re.search()` or `re.findall()`

Comment: See http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: Do you know what the atom `\b` means?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are putting \bblack\b. Why all the b's?

Comment: @msw: From how the question is asked, I think it is most likely the case he does...

Comment: @nhahtdh: oops, I did misread it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> #### `re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)`
>
> If zero or more characters at the beginning of *string* match the regular expression *pattern*, return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance.

You probably want to use `re.search` or `re.findall` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `re.search` or `re.findall` here:

```
>>> strs = 'blah black blacksheep blah'
>>> re.search(r'\bblack\b', strs).group(0)
'black'

>>> re.findall(r'\bblack\b', strs)
['black']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `re.search` instead of `re.match`.  From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match):

> **7.2.5.3. search() vs. match()**
>
> Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular
>   expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of
>   the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the
>   string (this is what Perl does by default).

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`re.search()`**](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.search) (returns None if no match on the whole string):

```
line = 'blah black blacksheep blah' 
if re.search(r'(\bblack\b)', line):
    print 'found it!
```